# Calculate MD5 of file being downloaded with PHP and CURL

Tags: php, curl, md5

I have some cURL call that download a large file.
I'm wondering if it is possible to calculate hash when the file is still downloading?

I think the progress callback function is the right place for accomplish that..

```
function get($urlget, $filename) {

        //Init Stuff[...]                   

        $this->fp = fopen($filename, "w+");
        $ch = curl_init();       


        //[...] irrelevant curlopt stuff

        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FILE, $this->fp);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_NOPROGRESS, 0);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROGRESSFUNCTION, array($this,'curl_progress_cb'));

        $httpCode = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);

        $ret = curl_exec($ch);

        if( curl_errno($ch) ){
            $ret = FALSE;
        }

        curl_close($ch);

        fclose($this->fp);        

        return $ret;
    }

    function curl_progress_cb($dltotal, $dlnow, $ultotal, $ulnow ){
        //... Calculate MD5 of file here with $this->fp

    }
```

Comment: How can MD5 make its full hash if the file is still downloading? Unless the owner of the file provides the MD5 hash, I don't see how you can.

Comment: The only point of an MD5 would be if the place you are getting the file **from** sent you the MD5 before (or possible after) you download the file so that you could check that the file **you received was the same as the file they transmitted** i.e. the file was not changed in transmission. You calculating the MD5 as the file is downloaded, or even when it is fully received by you, make no sence at all.

Comment: Calculating the MD5 as part of the curl_progress would mean calulating the MD5 more than once. That does not sound like it would save you time, in fact it sounds like it would increase your download time. if in fact it would generate the corret MD5 even when the last buffer was received

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its possible to calculate md5 hash of partially downloaded file, but it does not make too much sense. Every downloaded byte will change your hash diametrally, what is the reason behind going with this kind solution?

If you need to have md5 hash for entire file than the answer is NO. Your program has to first download the file and then generate the hash.

Comment: I have to download large files and after the download I have to put them in a catalog and store an hash for latter integrity check. Hashing file after the download requires time and I was looking for a solution in order to gain some time

Comment: Hashing every "block" will also take time, and be pretty meaningless

Answer (score -1):

I just do it:

in a file **wget-md5.php**, add the below code:

```
<?php
function writeCallback($resource, $data)
{
    global $handle;
    global $handle_md5_val;
    global $handle_md5_ctx;
    $len = fwrite($handle,$data);
    hash_update($handle_md5_ctx,$data);
    return $len;
}
$handle=FALSE;
$handle_md5_val=FALSE;
$handle_md5_ctx=FALSE;
function wget_with_curl_and_md5_hashing($url,$uri) 
{
    global $handle;
    global $handle_md5_val;
    global $handle_md5_ctx;
    $handle_md5_val=FALSE;
    $handle_md5_ctx=hash_init('md5');
    $handle = fopen($uri,'w');
    $curl = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL,                $url);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_BUFFERSIZE,         64000);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION,      'writeCallback');
    echo "wget_with_curl_and_md5_hashing[".$url."]=downloading\n";
    curl_exec($curl);
    curl_close($curl);
    fclose($handle);
    $handle_md5_val = hash_final($handle_md5_ctx);
    $handle_md5_ctx=FALSE;
    echo "wget_with_curl_and_md5_hashing[".$url."]=downloaded,md5=".$handle_md5_val."\n";
}
wget_with_curl_and_md5_hashing("http://archlinux.polymorf.fr/core/os/x86_64/core.files.tar.gz","core.files.tar.gz");
?>
```

and run:

```
$ php -f wget-md5.php
wget_with_curl_and_md5_hashing[http://archlinux.polymorf.fr/core/os/x86_64/core.files.tar.gz]=downloading
wget_with_curl_and_md5_hashing[http://archlinux.polymorf.fr/core/os/x86_64/core.files.tar.gz]=downloaded,md5=5bc1ac3bc8961cfbe78077e1ebcf7cbe

$ md5sum core.files.tar.gz 
5bc1ac3bc8961cfbe78077e1ebcf7cbe  core.files.tar.gz
```